# Cookie from nodeJS "secure: true" to a react-native app (expo)

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, session-cookies, express-session

I have to deal with a little problem.
I have a NodeJS backend which handle signup/signin (managed with express-session and passport).
No JWT here but session/cookie.

I have my front in vueJS (no problem here) and a react-native app (using **expo**).
I have the authentification process working.

I'd like to set "secure: true" option on the express-session parameters, for security enhancement. But as the definition tells, *"Secure : Ensures the browser only sends the cookie over HTTPS."*.

who to "make react native https" ?
because for now, the cookie isn't sent to the front (cause no https), so I can't keep the cookie id.

Thnak you !!

My react-native app works fine when "secure" is set to *false*, I already have all the code working.

Comment: `react-native` doesn't work in a browser, does it?

Comment: No it's for mobile app

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23185.